# Connect to WebMin from external network

Tags: user-interface, networking, nas, webmin

I have set up a new NAS using Open Media Vault. I have installed the WebMin extension to get on to the web gui for configuration. My problem is that I have to be on the same network as my NAS. How can I connect to my NAS from a different network than it is connected to? On the network that it is connected to its IP is 192.168.0.99:1000 for the WebMin gui. How can I access this from a different network?

Answer (score 0):

Setup a VPN to connect to the network that your NAS is on.  Once the VPN is connected you can connect to the NAS as if you were on the local network.

You could also possibly setup firewall and/or port forwarding rules depending on how your network is setup but please consider the security issues when doing so.

Answer (score 0):

You could alternatively also try to open the NAS and give it a public IP address and a DNS. This will allow you to setup SSH and FTP as it was any other server.

To SSH remotely over the internet, you need either a permanent IP address or a domain name that is updated to point to the IP address when it changes.  The latter requires a dynamic domain name service.  A good free one is DuckDNS (duckdns.org). First, use one of the sign-in options such as Google.  In the domain line enter your preferred subdomain name.

There is a great guide on how you can do this here: https://forums.freenas.org/index.php?threads/how-to-how-to-access-your-freenas-server-remotely-and-securely.27376/